# After scanning the image, using tflite model returns the result as null

Tags: android, kotlin, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tflite

I was following a tutorial on how to implement Image recognition function and I developed model with the Teacheable machine, but after scanning the image it would return null after catching the object name in  `Log.d("Catching message","${it.detectedObjectName}")`

It would sometimes provide with the confidence number.

Could it be the issue with code that I have implement of the model that I have been using? Perhaps I should implement some changes to the code that would fit the model?

Here is the UI implentation:

```
fun PlantAnalysisScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var classifications by remember {
        mutableStateOf(emptyList<Classification>()) }


    // Preparing Image Analyzer
    val imageAnalyzer =  remember {
        ImageAnalyzer(
            classifier = TfLitePlantClassifier(
                context = context
            ),
            onClassificationResults = {
                classifications = it
            }
        )
    }

    val cameraPreviewController = remember {
        LifecycleCameraController(context).apply {
            setEnabledUseCases(CameraController.IMAGE_ANALYSIS)
            setImageAnalysisAnalyzer(
                ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
                imageAnalyzer
            )
        }
    }
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            //TopBar
            TopAppBar(
                backgroundColor = TealPrimary,
                elevation = 0.dp
            ) {
                Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                        contentDescription = "Arrow Back",
                        tint = Color.White,
                        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                            navController.popBackStack()
                        })
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(120.dp))
                    Text(text = "Camera", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, color = Color.White,)
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(115.dp))

                }

            }

        }

    ) {
Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 160.dp)) {


        classifications.forEach {
            Row() {
                Text(
                    text = it.detectedObjectName,
                    modifier = Modifier

                        .padding(8.dp),

                    )
                Log.d("Catching message","${it.detectedObjectName}")

                Text(
                    text = it.confidenceScore.toString(),
                    modifier = Modifier

                        .padding(8.dp),

                    )
            }

    }
        CameraPreview(
            controller = cameraPreviewController,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )


    }}}
```

The TfLitePlantClassifier class:

```
class TfLitePlantClassifier (
    private val context: Context,
    private val confidenceThreshold: Float = 0.75f,
    private val maxResults: Int = 1
): PlantClassifier {
    private var classifier: ImageClassifier? = null

    override fun classifyCurrentFrame(bitmap: Bitmap, rotation: Int): List<Classification> {
        if (classifier == null) {
            initializeClassifier()
        }

        val tfLiteImageProcessingOptions = initializeImageProcessingOptions(rotation)
        val tfLiteImageProcessor: ImageProcessor = ImageProcessor.Builder().build()
        val tensorImage: TensorImage = tfLiteImageProcessor.process(
            TensorImage.fromBitmap(bitmap)
        )

        val classificationResults = classifier?.classify(
            tensorImage,
            tfLiteImageProcessingOptions
        )

        // Obtain each category from the result, map them to 'Classification' & lastly remove duplicates using 'distinctBy'
        return classificationResults?.flatMap { curClassification ->
            curClassification.categories.map { curCategory ->
                Classification(
                    detectedObjectName = curCategory.displayName,
                    confidenceScore = curCategory.score
                )
            }
        }?.distinctBy { it.detectedObjectName } ?: emptyList()
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the TfLite Image Classifier
     */
    private fun initializeClassifier() {
        val baseOptions = BaseOptions.builder()
            .setNumThreads(2)
            .build()

        val options = ImageClassifier.ImageClassifierOptions.builder()
            .setBaseOptions(baseOptions)
            .setMaxResults(maxResults)
            .setScoreThreshold(confidenceThreshold)
            .build()

        try {
            // Create the classifier from the TfLite File
            classifier = ImageClassifier.createFromFileAndOptions(
                context,
                "model.tflite",
                options
            )
        } catch (exception: IllegalStateException) {
            exception.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    /**
     * Builds and returns the TfLite ImageProcessingOptions
     *
     * @param rotation
     * @return ImageProcessingOptions
     */
    private fun initializeImageProcessingOptions(rotation: Int): ImageProcessingOptions {
        return ImageProcessingOptions.builder()
            .setOrientation(getOrientationFromRotation(rotation))
            .build()
    }

    /**
     * Returns the orientation of image from the rotation using the
     * TfLite ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation used to internally make use of image axes as an Image metadata
     *
     * @param rotation
     * @return ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation
     */
    private fun getOrientationFromRotation(rotation: Int): ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation {
        return when(rotation) {
            Surface.ROTATION_270 -> ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.BOTTOM_RIGHT
            Surface.ROTATION_90 -> ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.TOP_LEFT
            Surface.ROTATION_180 -> ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.RIGHT_BOTTOM
            else -> ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.RIGHT_TOP
        }
    }
}

ImageAnalyzer class:
```

class ImageAnalyzer(
private val classifier: PlantClassifier,
private val onClassificationResults: (List) -> Unit
): ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
private var frameSkipCounter = 0

```
override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
    // Analyze only 1 frame per-second
    if (frameSkipCounter % 60 == 0) {
        val rotationDegrees = image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees
        val bitmap = image
            .toBitmap()
            .centerCrop(321, 321)

        // Calling Domain layer classification method
        val classificationResults = classifier.classifyCurrentFrame(
            bitmap,
            rotationDegrees
        )
        onClassificationResults(classificationResults)
    }
    frameSkipCounter++

    // Fully processed the frame
    image.close()
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix it by including the `labels.txt` that I received from the Teachable machine in the assets.

Here is the code that I used to map the labels:

```
   private fun loadLabelsFromAsset(fileName: String): Map<Int, String> {
        val labels = mutableMapOf<Int, String>()
        try {
            val inputStream: InputStream = context.assets.open(fileName)
            val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))

            var line: String?
            while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                val parts = line?.trim()?.split(" ")
                if (parts != null && parts.size == 2) {
                    val index = parts[0].toIntOrNull()
                    val label = parts[1]
                    if (index != null) {
                        labels[index] = label
                    }
                }
            }

            reader.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return labels
    }
```

And then I changed this bit of code:

```
detectedObjectName = labels.getOrDefault(curCategory.label.toInt(), "Unknown"),
```

Now the code provides the result that I expect.